# Drupal 8 create a template override for a view block within a custom module

Tags: views, 8, theming, hooks

**The Question:**

In Drupal 8: How do I add a template override for a view block and have that twig file reside in a custom module - not my theme?

**Further Information:**

I have already created a custom module that creates a content type, imports data from an RSS feed and generates nodes into the content type it created.  The module also contains a view YML file so that the view for my content type is created when the module is installed.  The view only has one display which is a block.

I would like to create a template override for the block and house the template override within the module (rather than within my theme).  The template override does the following:

- Adds the appropriate classes to the block
- Adds an image beside the block title when the title is displayed
- Wraps the {{ content }} in a div with an appropriate class
- Loads the custom module's library to apply CSS

The goal is to have a module that a non-technical person can install, assign a block to the desired region and have all the templates, CSS, JS, etc pull from the module.  I don't want them to have to copy a template into their theme, etc.  I want the block to be a view so that the user can use the Views UI to make any desired updates to the view block's fields, number of returns, etc.

I was able to get Drupal to recognize the template by using hook_theme_registry_alter() but the variables from the block are null.  Both the {{ label }} and {{ content }} are null when I kint them in the template override.

Here is the hook_theme_registry_alter() code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook theme_registry_alter
 **/
function MYMODULE_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry){
  $theme_registry['block__views_block__MYVIEW_block_1']['path'] = drupal_get_path('module','MYMODULE') . '/templates/';
  $theme_registry['block__views_block__MYVIEW_block_1']['template'] = 'block--views-block--MYVIEW-block-1';
}
```

It should be noted that when I used hook_theme_registry_alter() for a view page template override in my module it worked.  My guess is that the variables were pulled from the page alias.

Please include detailed information because I am still learning about the various hooks and how variables are passed.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the same variables as a block template add it as base hook:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function mymodule_theme() {
  return [
    'block__views_block__MYVIEW_block_1' => [
      'render element' => 'elements',
      'base hook' => 'block',
    ],
  ];
}
```

Now you can place the twig template in `mymodule/templates/`, path and filename are discovered automatically.

Comment: I was also able to use this recommendation to override the views field template by returning something like this:
`'views_view_field__my_view__my_display__field_my_field' => [
      'render element' => 'elements',
      'base hook' => 'views field'
    ]
`

Comment: I just had to do something like this again:
`'views_view_table__my_view' => ['base hook' => 'views table']` (no "render elements" needed) allowed me to add a <tfoot> in my view.