# What's the difference between adding a template and overriding a template, from a custom module?

Tags: 8, theming, hooks

I found a paragraph [in the documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/howtos/using-template-tplphp-files-in-your-own-module#drupal8) about using template files in a custom module. This way can be even used to override a template like I did [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/269258/85453).

However, I am wondering if this is the correct way since I have read [this answer](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2015-06-03/drupal-8-override-template-with#comment-11572031).

After some research I noticed that we can see sometimes, depending on the case, the use of:

- `hook_theme` alone
- `hook_theme` with `hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter`
- `hook_theme_registry_alter`

What are the subtleties between these different ways to create or override a template?

The [documentation for hook_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme/8.2.x), which is not clear for me, states:

> The keys on the outer array are known as "theme hooks". For **theme
>   suggestions**, instead of the array key being the base theme hook, the
>   key is a theme suggestion name with the format
>   'base_hook_name__sub_hook_name'. For **render elements**, the key is the
>   machine name of the render element. The array values are themselves
>   arrays containing information about the theme hook and its
>   implementation.

Does this mean: "theme suggestions" for template overriding, and "render elements" for template creation?

To summarise, is there a difference between adding a template and overriding a template, from a custom module?
If so, what’s the correct way to add a template and the correct way to override a template?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drupal 8 create a template override for a view block within a custom module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/255813/drupal-8-create-a-template-override-for-a-view-block-within-a-custom-module)

Comment: Also see the other duplicates mentioned in this question: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/271288/15055

Comment: Thank you @leymannx, however all these threads do not really answer my question. I edited it to be more accurate about what I am asking. I hope it's clearer now and that someone can provide an answer that could serve as a reference on the subject.