# How do I include a twig file in a custom block type module?

Tags: 8, theming, blocks

I've created a custom module that creates a jumbotron custom block type. The module has an empty .module file and a dir config/install with many .yml files. This works great when I install and create blocks. I can even place my block--bundle--jumbotron.html.twig in the templates folder of the theme and styling works great! I would like this twig file included in the module and many tutorials explain how to do this if you have a build function in your module, I do not. The module is just creating a block type for me.

Comment: Have you tried placing the Twig file in a `templates` sub-folder in your module directory?

Comment: This only works if you add the template name as theme hook (with underscores) in mymodule.module, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/255813/drupal-8-create-a-template-override-for-a-view-block-within-a-custom-module

Comment: in the code in this example where 'block__views_block__MYVIEW_block_1' I'm not sure what to put here.

Comment: `'block__bundle__jumbotron'`

Comment: my 2 days of searching are over! thank you that finally worked!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a theme hook with the template name by replacing dashes with underscores:

*mymodule.module:*

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function mymodule_theme() {
  return [
    'block__bundle__jumbotron' => [
      'render element' => 'elements',
      'base hook' => 'block',
    ],
  ];
}
```

Comment: worked perfectly !